# how to custom getRelativeTimeSpanString

Tags: android, datetime, locale, timespan, relative-time-span

I want to use getRelativeTimeSpanString to show a date.but I couldn`t set Locale to this class for showing date base on my locale!
how can I custom this class?
is it possible to add locale as a parameter to this class?

```
final CharSequence relativeTimeSpanString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(createdTime.getTime());
```

also I set locale in my application:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lang)) {
        configuration.locale = new Locale(lang);
    } else {
        configuration.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    }
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

is there a way to solve this problem?

Finally I found Solution to this problem!

I used this method:

```
public static String getRelativeTimeSpanString(Context context, Date fromdate) {

    long then;
    then = fromdate.getTime();
    Date date = new Date(then);

    StringBuffer dateStr = new StringBuffer();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    int days = daysBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    int weeks= days/7;
    int minutes = hoursBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
    int hours = minutes / 60;
    if (days == 0) {

        int second = minuteBetween(calendar.getTime(), now.getTime());
        if (minutes > 60) {
            if (hours >= 1 && hours <= 24) {
                dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                        hours,
                        context.getString(R.string.hour)
                        ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
            }
        }else {
            if (second <= 10) {
                dateStr.append(context.getString(R.string.now));
            } else if (second > 10 && second <= 30) {
                dateStr.append(context.getString(R.string.few_seconds_ago));
            } else if (second > 30 && second <= 60) {
                dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                        second,
                        context.getString(R.string.seconds)
                        ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
            } else if (second >= 60 && minutes <= 60) {
                dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                        minutes,
                        context.getString(R.string.minutes)
                        ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
            }
        }
    } else

    if (hours > 24 && days < 7) {
        dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                days,
                context.getString(R.string.days)
                ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
    }else if(weeks == 1){
        dateStr.append(String.format("%s %s %s",
                weeks,
                context.getString(R.string.weeks)
                ,context.getString(R.string.ago)));
    }
    else {
        /**
         * make formatted createTime by languageTag("fa")
         *
         * @return
         */
        return SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG,new Locale("fra"))
                .format(date).toUpperCase();
    }

    return dateStr.toString();
}

public static int minuteBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int hoursBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}

public static int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return (int) ((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / android.text.format.DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

and I set date as a parameter to this method:

```
return getRelativeTimeSpanString(context,this.createdTime);
```

this return string by location as I want!

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code :

```
 Resources res = context.getResources();
 DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
 android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
 conf.locale = new Locale("fa");
 res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

final CharSequence relativeTimeSpanString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(oldDate, createdTime.getTime(),
     DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

Comment: I wanna show time span string by my language. DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL is for abbreviating suffix of time!